# Facebook app (iframed) and browser back button

Tags: facebook

I have a multipage Facebook app using iframe. Is there a way to make the browser back button behave properly with this setup? Currently when hitting the back button you are returning to the canvas page, even if you have navigated several pages down the app.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a Chrome browser ONLY problem. See http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/315455998483057?browse=search_4ef37cf5f2fdb4e45609648

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is No, you can not.

This has been the problem with IFRAME for ages, and has frustrated many a web developer.
The Back button is a HORRIBLE button, and IMHO should be removed from the browser world, however since I dont see that happening any time soon, here is something you can do.

The "best" thing you can do is use javascript to catch the event for when the browser tries to navigate away from the current top level page. From there you cna give the user a dialog asking them if they really want to leave the page or not.