# Enable browser back button in facebook app (iFrame) rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a "vanilla" restful routing rails app that is going to be a facebook app (iFrame).

Is there any way to enable the browser back button (history back)? Now it don't navigate back even if I go multiple links down.

Should I use jQuery address or similar, are there any gems helping me.

Does it have to be a ajax solution all the way.

Can I intersept the back click and invoke a "window.top.location" to the new url?

[Facebook app (iframed) and browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274389/facebook-app-iframed-and-browser-back-button/7274656#7274656)

This answer is not adequate as I have seen many facebook apps behaving the way I want.

Comment: This appears to be a Chrome browser ONLY problem. See http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/315455998483057?browse=search_4ef37cf5f2fdb4e45609648